# How to send a mail to all devise users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have 100 devise users on my rails app and I want to send them emails. I have the SMTP details and I am trying to follow this example http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised

My problem is I am not able to understand how to make it work ?

I have created

```
rails g mailer newsletter single_email
```

but I am little unsure how to take it from there, any help will be highly appreciated

EDIT - this is what I have so far, is this correct ?

```
# app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def newsletter(user)
    mail( to: user.email, subject: "Your subject")   
  end
end

# /lib/tasks/newsletter.rake

task :send_newsletter => :environment do
  User.all.each do |user|
    UserMailer.newsletter(user).deliver
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a rake task for that:

```
# /lib/tasks/newsletter.rake

task :send_newsletter => :environment do
  User.find_each do |user|
    UserMailer.newsletter(user).deliver
  end
end
```

This would iterate over all `Users` and invoke the `single_email` from the `NewsletterMailer` you created with your generator when you run `rake send_newsletter` from the command line.

The basic mailer would look something like this:

```
# /app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'newsletter@example.com'

  def newsletter(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'My newsletter')
  end
end
```

The view for the email that will be rendered by `mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'My newsletter')` looks like this:

```
# app/views/user_mailer/newsletter.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>more text...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example assumes your `User` model has a `name` - it's only to show you that you have access to `@user` in your mailer view, because you set `@user` in `def newsletter(user)` before.

Comment: btw I already have user_mailer.rb file, so can't I just add def single_email function to it ? also what parameter should I pass to single_email function ?

Comment: @iCyborg yes, each mailer can have as many mail functions as you like - you do not have to create a separate one for each. You need to pass it all the objects it needs to do its job: at the minimum, that would be the email address of the recipient. Everything else depends on what you use to create that email - the recipients' name, other objects etc…

Comment: Thanks, I have put the current code which I have in question, is it correct ?

Comment: @iCyborg I'll update my answer with a short example in a second. Try the official [ActionMailer guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, looks great, I am running the code, if I get stuck, will comment here, accepting it as the answer

Comment: replace `all.each` by `find_each`

Comment: Better way is using `#pluck(:email)` which will return only emails (of course if you do not personalize mails).

Comment: Hi @janfoeh - just wondering, is there any way to test the code/email for just one user ? say with user id = 1 ? as I am worried if something goes wrong, every user will get spammed

Comment: @iCyborg just send one mail from the Rails console to your own user (I assume it's ID 1): `UserMailer.newsletter( User.find(1) ).deliver`

Comment: @iCyborg also, take a look at the [mails-viewer gem](https://github.com/pragmaticly/mails_viewer).

Answer (score 1):

it depends from where and when you want to send this email

```
def single_email(users_email)
 mail( to: users_email, subject: "Your subject")
end
```

Now from controller or model you can invoke it. also create an html for the email

```
 NewsletterMailer.single_email(User.all.map(&:email).join(';')).deliver
```

Comment: I want to send the email immediately so no scheduling is needed but I am not sure how to trigger that single_email action ? can you clarify this with more detail ? thanks

Comment: You can put this line NewsletterMailer.single_email(User.all.map(&:email).join(';')).deliver in any action of your controller . put that on root controller. you can also put that in the initializer so when you restart your server it will trigger that action

Comment: Thanks, I have put the current code which I have in question, is it correct ?

Comment: This will send mail to each user individually . so if 100 user it will send 100 mail which will take a long time . i am not sure about your need if you have to send some dynamic content such as username in the mail than you can use sendgrid for that or if your Content is same for  all users just pass email of all user seperatd by ; in a single time

Comment: Hi, is this solution better than what janfoeh suggested above ? I am still unsure how to invoke this method from controller or model ?

Comment: This solution is better if you want sending email to all user at once.  lets say you have mapped route to home#index than just paste the line NewsletterMailer.single_email(User.all.map(&:email).join(';')).deliver in the index action of home controller and hit your home page . through browser